# GRAPHQL find items based on Enum

Tags: enums, graphql, prisma, graphiql

I am trying to find the results that match a certain enum, this is my `type` :

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  fname:String!
  lname:String!
  email:String! @unique
  password: String
  school_ID: String #@relation(Link: INLINE)
  role: [Role] @scalarList(strategy: RELATION)
  resetToken: String
  resetTokenExpiry: String
}
```

I can search for email because it has the `@unique` key to it, but `Role` is an enum and I can't add the `@unique` key to it and that makes sense, because the results are not going to be unique.

However I keep getting this message:

> "Variable \"$_v0_where\" got invalid value {\"role\":\"TEACHER\"}; Field \"role\" is not defined by type UserWhereUniqueInput."

Using email gives me the result I want if I want to use email to find the items.

What I am after is to get an array return with all the objects matching the selected enum result.

In my schema I have this:

```
users: [User]!
user(where: UserWhereInput!): User
findUser(role: Role, id: ID, email: String): User
```

In my query resolvers I have the following that I am playing with:

```
  users: forwardTo('db'),
  user: forwardTo('db'),

  async findUser(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    return ctx.db.query.user({
      where: {email: args.email, id: args.id, role: args.role}
    }, info)
  },
```

I am using prisma (1.17.1) to generate my schemas

How do I alter my code, or the `findUser` function to give me the desired result?

Comment: This question appears to be specific to Prisma, not GraphQL or Apollo. You should update your tags accordingly and indicate what version of Prisma you're running.

Comment: @DanielRearden done :-) - I still think it is related to GraphQL though since i am sorting out my schema

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ctx.db.query.user` function with the following signature:

```
user: (where: UserWhereUniqueInput) => UserNullablePromise;
```

As you can see it requires the `UserWhereUniqueInput` type where condition. Why? Because the user function should always only return one distinct unique object. On the other hand there is also a `ctx.db.query.users` function:

```
  users: (args?: {
    where?: UserWhereInput;
    orderBy?: UserOrderByInput;
    skip?: Int;
    after?: String;
    before?: String;
    first?: Int;
    last?: Int;
  }) => FragmentableArray<User>;
```

As you can see this function has more options and uses `UserWhereInput` to define the where condition. This will also include the role of the user in your case. This function can return multiple objects and it is up to you to filter / handle accordingly.

Hint: You can also inspect the generated prisma client yourself. The path will usually be something like `src\generated\prisma-client\index.ts`. In there you can see the interface definitions of all functions, the `UserWhereUniqueInput` as well as the `UserWhereInput` for example. This way you can check what is possible and what is not.